# read line with .encode with utf8

Tags: python, unicode, utf-8

I read line from a file like:

> The Little Big Things: 163 Wege zur Spitzenleistung (Dein Leben) (German Edition) (Peters, Tom)
>
> Die virtuelle Katastrophe: So führen Sie Teams über Distanz zur
>   Spitzenleistung (German Edition) (Thomas, Gary)

I read / encode them with:

```
title = line.encode('utf8')
```

but the output is:

> b'Die virtuelle Katastrophe: So f\xc3\xbchren Sie Teams \xc3\xbcber
>   Distanz zur Spitzenleistung (German Edition) (Thomas, Gary)'
>
> b'The Little Big Things: 163 Wege zur Spitzenleistung (Dein Leben)
>   (German Edition) (Peters, Tom)'

Why is the "b'" always added?
How do I properly read the files so that the "Umlauts" are preserved?

Here is the complete relevant code snippet:

```
# Parse the clippings.txt file
lines = [line.strip() for line in codecs.open(config['CLIPPINGS_FILE'], 'r', 'utf-8-sig')]
for line in lines:
    line_count = line_count + 1
    if (line_count == 1 or is_title == 1):
        # ASSERT: this is a title line
        #title = line.encode('ascii', 'ignore')
        title = line.encode('utf8')
        prev_title = 1
        is_title = 0
        note_type_result = note_type = l = l_result = location = ""
        continue
```

thanks

Comment: `b''`means that you got a byte buffer, not an (unicode) string as is to be expected from `encode()`, which turns a string into an encoded byte sequence. In your case, you need to `decode()` *from* utf-8, not encode *to* utf-8. Or even better, use [`codecs.open(..., encoding='utf-8')`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#codecs.open). For a proper answer I'd like to see more of your code, though.

Comment: @dhke It might be enough just to remove that `.encode` line, because the output looks like correct UTF-8, meaning `line` was already a valid Unicode string.

Comment: @melpomene That works, when the default encoding is *utf-8*, yes.

Comment: @dhke I added the code. I already use codecs.open (was used in the base I used for changing this script to fit my needs). Using .decode or removing .encode results in an error

Comment: @f0rd42 I see. And looking at the snippet, you should be able to simply drop the encode part altogether. At this point, `line` is already a (decoded) Python string. `'\xc3\xb'` is also correct *utf-8* for German `ü`. What did make you think, the umlauts are not read correctly? Do they display incorrectly on output?

Comment: @f0rd42 "results in an error" is very unhelpful. What's the error message?

Comment: @melpomene `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'` ;-). It's Python 3 and the Python 3 string doesn't have a `decode()`, because it's already decoded.

Comment: @dhke OK, I can see that happening from using `.decode`, but what's the error from removing `.encode`?

Comment: just doing a "title = line" does anything I need. I looked the code as a basis for my needs. Thanks to you both

Answer (score 5):

The method `str.encode` turns a unicode string into a `bytes` object:

> **`str.encode(encoding="utf-8", errors="strict")`**
>   Return an encoded version of the string as a bytes object. Default encoding is 'utf-8'. errors may be given to set a different error handling scheme. The default for errors is 'strict', meaning that encoding errors raise a UnicodeError. Other possible values are 'ignore', 'replace', 'xmlcharrefreplace', 'backslashreplace' and any other name registered via codecs.register_error(), see section Error Handlers. For a list of possible encodings, see section Standard Encodings.

So what you get is exactly what is expected.

On most machines, you can just `open` the files and read. If the file encoding is not the system default, you can pass it as keyword argument:

```
with open(filename, encoding='utf8') as f:
    line = f.readline()
```